# In app purchases have different price listed on playstore then in play console

Tags: android, google-play

My app shows different price for in app purchases then what i have put in Google play console but in my app when i purchase product the amount is different then what i put in play console and in playstore the amount listed is also different so what is the issue? Is it on my end or is it about playstore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: put screenshots of your listed price , and where you are seeing the price different

Comment: This may be the issues for countries like the US, where VAT is not included in the Play Console price, but added on later.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it shows the prices per country. Let's say you've entered $5.00 as a default price for the IAP, hence you will see the price get automatically converted and populated in the "Local prices" list below. For example, the price might be automatically overridden as $4.99 for the USA, which you can manually update to $5.00 again.

[image]